# Return type of read method in InputStream class

Tags: java

why read() method of InputStream class return int instead of byte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you read [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), you'll see it explains why:

> The value byte is returned as an int in the range 0 to 255. If no byte is available because the end of the stream has been reached, the value -1 is returned.

Comment: ok then what is the reason behind having int parameter of write(int) method of OutputStream ?

Comment: mere symmetry/convenience, I guess.